# The UI of Settings App of Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I tried to find a lot about this. I was never satisfied by any answers.

Please look at the below two images:

[image: Simple Tabs]
[image: Modified Tabs]

The action bar tabs in the first image are simple without any formatting. But the action bars in second image has a different style. Only 3 tabs being shown at a time with left and the right being aligned to extremes and the center tab being present at the center.

When I am trying to add tabs in my application, tabs are added with default formats. I read about styles and themes. But I am not able to generate the one in the second image.

How can I achieve the style (as in image 02) in my application? Is there any package or is it something different from tabs?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: "The action bar tabs in the first image are simple without any formatting" -- how have you determined that those are action bar tabs, instead of something else? "But the action bars in second image has a different style. Only 3 tabs being shown at a time with left and the right being aligned to extremes and the center tab being present at the center" -- how have you determined that those are action bar tabs, instead of something else? The second one, in particular, is probably something based off of `PagerTabStrip`.

Comment: Yes, I got it. PagerTabStrip. Thanks.